# Edit text weird behavior

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, android-viewholder

I have an ExpandableListView which contains a RecyclerView of a custom layout. This layout contains some views including my EditText.

My behavior is : When I click in my **number** EditText, the keyboard appears for about 0.5s, the whole layout is cleared with default values, then the keyboard disappears, a **text** EditText appears, and finally I loose focus. When I click on it one more time, the keyboard stays, but in **text** type. Strange thing : the problem seems to be only on devices where the whole layout overflows the screen because on 10" tablet, everything is ok (layout not cleared, and keyboard not disappearing).

According to me, when I get the focus in the EditText, the layout is re-creates , making it to be cleared.

I tried a long time to figure out what was going on, but I didn't find anything. Here is the things I tried, but didn't change anything :

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" // on all parent of the EditText

focusable="true" // On the EditText

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" // In the activity in the manifest

making all the ViewHolder attributes final
```

As the code is very huge for all that amount of things, I don't know what I should post to help. So don't hesitate to ask anything if it can help

Thanks!

EDIT : A Gif showing the issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqfiV.jpg

Comment: it looks like the keyboards make a 'scroll' in the recycler view making it change the objects in it

Comment: have you tried on different devices is there a same issue ?

Comment: have you checked if your edit texts are not getting disabled somewhere, its very difficult to follow, can you make a gif file of this behaviour and attach

Comment: I just edited my post with the GIF showing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your activity on `manifest.xml`:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Opening keyboard or screen size changes may trigger to re-create your content.

Comment: Sadly, it does not change anything